# Getting a 404 on Nginx RTMP Module stats file

Tags: xslt, nginx, module, rtmp

I'm not understanding why I get a 404 when I set up my stats view in Nginx RTMP Module.

The instructions I'm following are fairly [straightforward](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) and especially [here](http://www.helping-squad.com/nginx-rtmp-setup-rtmp-statistics/).

I'm using a Ubuntu VM on Google Cloud.

I've placed my stat.xsl file in /var/www/html

That is the default location for Nginx assets, as specified in sites-enabled/default folder:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

     location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

And here is the snippet I copy/pasted and adapted in my nginx.conf:

```
server{
                listen 80;
                 location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
                 }


                location /stat.xsl {
            # you can move stat.xsl to a different location
            # under linux you could use /var/user/www for example
                root html;
                }

        }
```

The goal here is to be able to type [my-ip-address/stat and get the formatted xsl content.

There's something here I'm not getting -any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing /statOR instead?

```
 server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;

    # rtmp statistics
    location /stat {
        rtmp_stat all;
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
    }

    location /stat.xsl {
        # you can move stat.xsl to a different location
        # under linux you could use /var/user/www for example
        root html;
```